# I am using twitter bootstrap and my <img> tag is not working! Wont display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, symbols, nomethoderror

I've been trying to set up my login but keep reaching an error page that says:

```
"NoMethodError in Static_pages#welcome" "undefined method `id' for :user:Symbol"
```

So when I paste the following into :

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<% if current_user %>
Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>
<%= link_to "Log Out", log_out_path %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %>
<%= link_to "Log in", log_in_path %>
<% end %>
</div>

<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
<%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>
```

Without it the layout shows up but with it it goes to error...
The sign_up page seems to show but that's about it.. so confused...

Answer (score 0):

In your `StaticPages` controller's `welcome` method you are trying to find the `id` of a [symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html):

```
> :user.id
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for :user:Symbol
```

Presumably you mean to be calling `id` on the `user` variable:

```
> user.id
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just had to add the ID to User as so :user_id inside the hash... :) Thank you!!!!!!